# Data Validation range from different spreadsheets with onEdit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

I have in my source spreadsheet a dropdown with data validation of a range from another tab in the same spreadsheet with data imported from another spreadsheet with the following script.

The main spreadsheet is very slow cause I have a lot of tab with data imported with the script, so how can I create an onEdit trigger on my source spreadsheet which would update the data validation when the other spreadsheet are edited?

The script:

```
function importSheetA() {
var values1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx').
  getSheetByName('xxxxx').getRange('A1:EO2000').getValues(); 
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('masterop').
  getRange(1,1,values1.length,values1[0].length).setValues(values1);  
}
```

**Update:**

With this script I can show the dropdown on 1 sheet ("id1").
How to do this for many spreadsheets ID?

```
function installTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('changeValidationRule').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
}

function changeValidationRule(e) {
  let values = e.source.getRange("A1:A3").getValues().flatMap(value => value); //flatting the row structures into a single dimension array
  let sourceSheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById("id1").getSheets()[0];
  let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(values, true); // The boolean stands for `show dropdown`
  sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1).setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify this: "when the other spreadsheet are edited?" to which spreadsheet are you referring to? You want to listen to edit events on the source spreadsheet, but the data validation is based on imported values that come from another sheet right? So you should listen to edit events on the data validation values sheet, right?

Comment: Yes, I would to update the data of the data validation from the sheets imported only when these sheets are updated.

Answer (score 1):

### Approach

You can achieve this behavior using Apps Script `onEdit()` installable Trigger.

The trigger has to be installed because it will need authorization to access the source Spreadsheet.

The trigger will be placed in the validation sheet, and will trigger when this is manually updated. The trigger will run a function that will update the validation rule based on the values that you want to take in account.

For simplicity, I assumed that the values are in a column in the validation sheet in the range `A1:A3`.

I will fetch these values and I will build a Validation rule on the desired range on the source spreadsheet.

### Code

```
function installTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('changeValidationRule').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
}

function changeValidationRule(e) {
  let values = e.source.getRange("A1:A3").getValues().flatMap(value => value); //flatting the row structures into a single dimension array
  // Initialize the variables
  let ids = ['id1','id2','id3']; // Add here the ids of your source sheets
  let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(values, true); // The boolean stands for `show dropdown`
  // Loop through the ids and update the rule
  ids.map(id => {
      let sourceSheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets()[0];
      sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1).setDataValidation(rule);
  });
  
}
```

### Disclaimer

In your example you import those values in the source spreadsheet. You can actually reference a Range in your source spreadsheet, but I consider using a values list easier, since we are working directly on the validation spreadsheet. I will put a reference to this method below.

### Edit

There is a limit on value items you can use in a validation rule. This limit is 500 items. If you need to validate more than 500 items there is no other way than to import all the values in a Validation Sheet in your Source Spreadsheet. You will be able to reference this range in your Data Validation Rule and you can build a script that updates this range whenever the Validation Spreadsheet changes. Here is an idea:

```
function installTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateValidationRange').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
}

function updateValidationRange(e) {
  let values = e.source.getRange("a-big-range-in-validation-spreadsheet").getValues();
  // Initialize the variables
  let ids = ['id1','id2','id3'];
  // Loop through the ids and update the rule
  ids.map(id => {
      let sourceSheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Validation Sheet"); // Be sure to change this name in order to reflect your validation sheet inside the source Spreadsheet
      sourceSheet.getRange("the-copy-of-the-big-range-in-the-source-spreadsheet").setValues(values); // It's crucial this range is the same size than the one in the validation spreadsheet
  });
  
}
```

### References

[requireValueInList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinlistvalues,-showdropdown)

[requireValueInRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinrangerange,-showdropdown)

[installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: It works. Now, I need to have several Source Sheets in which run the validation. How to do that? Can I add another string: let sourceSheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById("source-spreadsheet-id").getSheets()[0]; ??

Comment: Exactly! Just select all your sheets and perform this operation in each of them.

Comment: I have this 2 strings in your code now:
  let sourceSheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID1").getSheets()[0];
  let sourceSheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID2").getSheets()[0];
But I have this error: SyntaxError: Identifier 'sourceSheet' has already been declared (riga 7, file "Codice.gs")

Comment: You are declaring the same variable twice. In computer programming variables are unique identifiers used to store information. In this case you are using Javascript to program Apps Script. Use a different variable name for each Spreadsheet.

Comment: I have duplicated this function changeValidationRule(e) {
  let values = e.source.getRange("A1:A3").getValues().flatMap(value => value); //flatting the row structures into a single dimension array
  let sourceSheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById("source-spreadsheet-id").getSheets()[0];
  let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(values, true); // The boolean stands for `show dropdown`
  sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1).setDataValidation(rule);
} with a different ID. It is correct?

Comment: What do you want to do? Please update your question, don't paste code in the comments because it's very hard to read.

Comment: See now the question.

Comment: I edited the answer so it will be more dynamic for your purpose

Comment: Seems good. But If I would have for each ID a specific range? (In this case (1,1).

Comment: I think you should create another question for that

Comment: Ok. I will do it now.

Comment: I've tried with a range like A1:A8000, but not works... Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217584/discussion-between-popoff-and-alessandro).